# CollectionView Layout after rotate

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that shows my photo library. After I select a cell, it will segue to another collection view which the cell frame is full-screen size.

The portrait orientation seems fine. However, when I rotate to landscape, something messes up.

When there is no `viewWillTransition`, the `itemSize` will not reshape, so it just like the image below.

[image]

With `viewWillTransition`, the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` will be called, and the `itemSize` reshaped. However, it is still not expected, any suggestions?

[image]

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return self.view.bounds.size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: why did you made code  for collectionview .?

Comment: because you have done segue then you need to add code in that class.

Answer (score 0):

extend class with UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height-20)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    return 0
}
```